# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 >= 1

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, jtable, conditional-statements

What is happening?
the first time it runs everything goes well but if it is executed a second time it fails even if it meets the for condition:

```
private void actualizar_screen(){
        DefaultTableModel tabla = (DefaultTableModel) screen_table.getModel();
        int total_rows = tabla.getRowCount();
        int i=0;
        System.out.println("Total items: "+items);
        System.out.println("Total rows: "+total_rows);
        for(i=0;i<items;i++){
            System.out.println("i = "+i);
            tabla.removeRow(i);
        }
        System.out.println("Removidas "+i+" de items "+items);
}
```

the console shows the following

```
Total items: 1
Total rows: 1
i = 0
Removidas 1 de items 1

Total items: 2
Total rows: 2
i = 0
i = 1

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 >= 1
```

Comment: When you remove the row your `items` (or `total_rows`) count becomes invalid (because you just removed a value).

Comment: Where is `items` set?

Comment: Change: `for(i=0;i<items;i++)` to: `for(i=items-1; i >= 0; i--)`

Comment: When you remove row 0, the previous row 1 becomes row 0.  When you then try to remove row 1, there's nothing there to remove.  The suggestion that @alfasin made deals with that by removing the last row first, and counting downwards.  Please try it.

Comment: already works friend, but when there is only 1 row left wanting to remove it shows error

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1> = 1

Comment: Re-read my comment and you'll understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problem in loop to remove:

```
Total items: 2 --> items = 2
Total rows: 2 --> tabla.getRowCount() = 2, row index 0, 1 exist
i = 0 --> then remove row index 0, so tabla.getRowCount() = 1 -> row index 0 exist
i = 1 --> then remove row index 1 --> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: index >= length
```

To fix your code, just use `tabla.removeRow(0);` to remove first row.
Or use while loop:

```
while(i < items) {
    System.out.println("i = "+ i++);
    tabla.removeRow(0);
}
```

Comment: Perfect, it worked wonders. I understood my mistake, thank you very much